# Shouldn't the result still be c(1,2,3)?

Tags: r

So, if I run this

```
df = data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,0))
df= df[-which(df$a == 0),]
```

As expected, the result would be c(1,2,3). But if there is no 0 as:

```
df = data.frame(a= c(1,2,3))
df= df[-which(df$a == 0),]
```

This will return an empty vector. Shouldn't the result still be c(1,2,3)?

Answer (score 2):

`df$a == 0` is `c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)`.

`which(df$a == 0)` is an empty integer vector.

Negating an empty vector *still* yields an empty vector.

And subsetting with an empty vector, unfortunately, *also* yields an empty vector.

The solution in this case would be to use logical indexing and dropping the use of `which`. This should *generally* be done in this case:

```
df[! df$a == 0, ]
# or:
df[df$a != 0, ]
```

This *always* yields the correct solution; no need for `which`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Now i know negating an empty vector still yields an empty vector :(